# Regex to permit only certain characters

Tags: regex

I have a working regex that matches at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 digit:

```
"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
```

I'm trying to modify to only permit an underscore, dollar sign or pound sign, `_ $ £` I'm not sure how to approach this. This is not correct:

```
"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z_$£])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
```

For example:

```
'Pa$$w0rd' - true
'orange1_' - false
'Apple22_' - true
'Banana100_!' - false
```

What is wrong with the example?

Comment: Powershell? Do you want to add another *required* pattern? Then use `"^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^_$£]*[_$£]).*"`

Comment: Did you mean "only permit" or "also permit"? Or "also require"?

Comment: @tobias_k also permit

Comment: @LightningWar But your original regex already permits those, it just requires the others.

Comment: Why is `Banana100_!` invalid? 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit,  1 `_` are present.

Comment: @tobias_k it needs to permit, but not require. Or more clearly: not allow `!&*(){}"` for example. Not sure it's possible..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `!` is not valid. only `$ £ _`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex already permits all those characters. If I understand your question correctly, you want to permit *only* those special characters (besides letters and digits). In this case, you should change the `.*` at the end of your regex to `[\d\w$£]*` (`_` is included in `\w`):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\d\w$£]*$
```

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/6ZpaD2/2